# Problem in making a field Required

Tags: required-field

I have multiple sections on page. I am rendering these sections using a list. I want fields in first section to be required only. so I have used an apex:variable which I am incrementing within apex:repeat. I have used condition with apex:inpufield required attribute.

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!obj[myInfo.fieldPath]}" required="{!IF(srNo==1 ,true,false)}"/>
```

with this condition I am getting red bar in front of the field but on submitting the page, it is not validating that field. why this is happening?

Comment: How are you surfacing `srNo`?

Comment: i am using it in repeat as apex:variable

Comment: Do you have `immediate="true"` on your submit button?

Comment: No. i do not have immediate="true". i have few other fields on the page also, they are validating accordingly.

Comment: Are you using a Standard Controller with a custom extension, or a custom controller?

Comment: @Pankaj is `srNo` actually number `1` or a string `'1'`?

Comment: @Pankaj THe whole statement you have put up in value. I am quite surprised that we can use value like this as well.Any reference that you can suggest which would help in knowing more on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it might be a bug.  If you're seeing the red bar next to the right fields you can safely assume that the required flag is getting set correctly.

Things that override field requirements to consider:

**Immediate Flag**

If you set the immediate attribute of the any action element (i.e. commandButton) to true the action method will execute before any validations and the required field gets ignored.

**Action Region**

If you're using an `apex:actionRegion` tag only data within that tag is getting sent to the controller in the post back and the required field check won't occur

**Non-Standard Submit**

If you're submit action occurs via a webservice or apex remoting it's bypassing the usual form submit and the required field check.

**Bugs**

If nothing else is making sense it may just be a bug in the platform.  You can submit a case to support, but it's probably a lot quicker just to enforce the check yourself in the controller.